# Compress log files which are older than 5 days using log4j2

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Currently, my logs are generating 1 file per day.
But I want to compress the log files older than 5 days and delete them after 10 days.

how can I achieve this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/server.log"
                 filePattern="logs/server_%d{date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: We didn't use log4j for this and I'm not sure it actually will be able to compress and delete older log files as this would require a separate process. What we've been using is the `logrotate` tool on Linux machines to achieve what you're asking for.

Comment: The above (logrotate) makes sense, even *if* the app in question is running as a daemon, since this kind of housekeeping is a job for the OS.